# my program is not adding items to listbox and is freezing up

Tags: sql, vb.net

im trying to add a very large amount of items to list box and what i need it for is i'm using to add selected items to itextsharp table report im using filters in the table just to display either the sales person who handled the customer or the date at which the incident occurred (or Issue was reported with the product) my filter system is as follows i have 4 categories which is 4 listboxes customer name, customer code(named listBox1 i have not got around to changing it yet) species name, and the error type my filter is placed under the searchBtn_Click event my filter and item adding code is as follows:

```
Private Sub searchBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searchBtn.Click

        For Each obj As contactObject In custList
            For Each item As speciesObject In speciesList
                'loadLists()

                If Trim(fromDate.Value) < Trim(obj.eventDate) Then
                    If Trim(toDate.Value) > Trim(obj.eventDate) Then
                        If Trim(fromDate.Value) < Trim(item.compDate) Then
                            If Trim(toDate.Value) > Trim(item.compDate) Then

                            End If



                            If Not customerListBox.Items.Contains(obj.customerName) Then
                                customerListBox.Items.Add(obj.customerName)
                            End If
                            If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(obj.customer) Then
                                ListBox1.Items.Add(obj.customer)
                            End If
                            If Not speciesListBox.Items.Contains(item.name) Then
                                If ListBox1.Items.Contains(item.customerCode) Then
                                    speciesListBox.Items.Add(Trim(item.name).ToUpper)
                                End If
                            End If
                            If Not errorListBox.Items.Contains(obj.issue + "    -   " + obj.issueDescription) Then
                                errorListBox.Items.Add(Trim(obj.issue + "    -   " + obj.issueDescription).ToUpper)

                            End If

                        End If
                        End If
                    End If
 Next
        Next

        countErrors()

    End Sub
```

then i have the query which is set up to get the customer info from the database system

```
Dim SqlText As String = "SELECT DISTINCT QEE.[EventID]  ,QEE.[EventDate]  ,QEE.[Employee]  ,QEE.[Communication]  ,QEE.[OtherCommunication]  ,QEE.[Issue]  ,QEE.[IssueDescription]  ,QEE.[IssueComments]  ,QEE.[Resolution]  ,QEE.[ResolutionComments]  ,QEE.[SalesOrderNumber]  ,QEE.[CustomerPO]  ,QEE.[SOStatus]  ,QEE.[Customer]  ,QEE.[CustomerName]  ,QEE.[SalesPersonName]  ,QEE.[IsResolved]  ,QEE.[IssueValue]  ,QEE.[DateAndTimeAdded]  ,DATEDIFF(day, SOR.ReqShipDate, QEE.[EventDate]) AS Elapsed, SOR.ReqShipDate FROM [QualityTracking].[dbo].[tblQualityEventEntry] QEE  INNER JOIN SysproCompanyC.dbo.SorMaster SOR  ON QEE.SalesOrderNumber = SOR.SalesOrder COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS   ORDER BY EventDate ASC, CustomerName ASC, SalesOrderNumber ASC;"
```

***I could not fit all code on here***

if you could also just general things to help as well i am new to vb.net but for other information things i have tried :
*listbox.startUpdate/endUpdate
*changing querys
*changing the sorted property (Right now its set for false)
*the issue happens when i choose select all and then hit search the database is holding almost 2Mil items and i need to be able to get it to move once i get it work stop freezing i will be able to increase the speed i just cant figure out totally where the issue is i know the query could be better probably (if you have any suggestions please feel free i'm learning)
*but i also see alot of people having this issue with listbox as being kinda a broken down way of listing items 
*i have tried researching it and people have said use something else i cant do that for listbox is committed

Comment: As of now, your *"very large amount of items"* are raising a *"very large amount of messages"*. Collect the items, then update each view either by setting a new `DataSource` or use `Items.AddRange`.

Comment: Did the answer provided help you in any way?

Comment: no it did not but i did solve my own issue, the suspend layout does not work or did not work or do anything that i saw i even stepped through and it didnt

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [**Windows Forms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms).

You program might not be responding because of too many records to add, and each time you add an item into the [**ListBox.Items**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection, the UI is refreshed.

You may either [**SuspendLayout**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) while adding the lines into your [**Listbox**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx), and [**ResumeLayout**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout(v=vs.110).aspx) afterwards.

```
Private Sub searchBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    customerListBox.SuspendLayout();
    // Place your code to populate the ListBox control here...
    customerListBox.ResumeLayout();
End sub
```

This shall avoid a lot of refreshes from occuring while adding the items one by one and allow the application to lighten the add of items, then you resume the layout so that it refreshes the controls to display adequate information to the screen.

**OR**

You may use the [**ListBox.Items.AddRange()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx) method along with [**List.ToArray()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Private Sub searchBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim custList As List(Of ConstactObject) = loadYourCustomers();
    customerListBox.Items.AddRange(custList.ToArray());

    Dim speciesList As List(Of SpeciesObject) = loadYourSpecies();
    speciesListBox.Items.AddRange(speciesList.ToArray());
End sub
```

**OR ELSE**

I recommend using a [**DataGridView**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) and setting its [**DataSource**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) property to your list of objects.

So, in order to have the correct data, you'll have to:

1. Drop two **`DataGridView`** on your [**Form**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Rename both **`DataGridView`** to a meaningful name (e.g. `custListDataGridView`, `speciesListDataGridview`)
3. Drop two [**BindingSource**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) on your **`Form`**
4. Rename both **`BindingSource`** to a meaningful name (e.g. `custListBindingSource`, `speciesListBindingSource`)
5. In the designer, set the **`DataGridView.DataSource`** property to your respective **`BindingSource`** (e.g. `custListDataGridview.DataSource = custListBindingsource`, `speciesListDataGridView.DataSource = speciesListBindingSource`)
6. In the backing code, that is, in your `searchBtn.Click` event, you may set both your binding sources **`DataSource`** property

   ```
   Private Sub searchBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
       Dim custList As IList(Of ContactObject) =  loadYourContactObjects();
       custListBindingSource.DataSource = custList;

       Dim speciesList As IList(Of SpeciesObject) = loadYourSpeciesObject();           
       speciesListBindingSource.DataSource = speciesList;
   End Sub
   ```

And your information data should be listed automatically without you having to manually add each record.